# MAC | Access application deployed on Docker from another application on VirtualBox machine

Tags: docker, virtualbox, aem

**Machine** - MAC bookPro `Mac OSx 10.11.6`

**Docker** - Docker for mac `Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e`

**VirtualBox** - `Version 5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2)`

I have my AEM (CMS) running on an image on Virtual Box, provisioned using Vagrant + Chef. We allocate IP explicitly to the box - 192.168.x.x

We have introduced a Microservice  (Spring boot + MySQL) that we wish to deploy using Docker.
On my local (MAC) I successfully get Microservice up and running and two docker instances (Microservice, MySQL) connecting to each other successfully. The Microservice exposes certain end-points that I need to invoke from my AEM running in Virtual box. This is something I am not able to do, My virtualbox instance is not able to connect to docker hosted app (the ip of docker machine is not accessible within my virtualbox)

I use docker compose to get my docker instances working -

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    #build:
    #  context: ./registration-database
    image: mysql
    container_name: afs-mysql
    #network_mode: "bridge"
    # set default mysql root password, change as needed
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: afs_service
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    # Expose port 3306 to host. Not for the application but
    # handy to inspect the database from the host machine.
    ports:
      - "3309:3306" 
    restart: always

  webserver:
    container_name: afs-microservice
    #network_mode: "bridge"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
   # build: 
   #   context: ./registration-webserver
    image: afs-service
    # mount point for application in tomcat
    #volumes:
    #  - ./app/target/UserSignup:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/UserSignup
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_USER: root
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: root
      DATABASE_NAME: afs_service
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
    # open ports for tomcat and remote debugging
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
      - "8089:8089"
    restart: always
```

What additional needs to be done so that I can access docker exposed application from virtualbox.

Comment: If you use newer docker-for-mac that **don't** involves docker-machine, you get the exposed ports in the host interface, so it is easier to access there from the vagrant machine (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach any docker-for-mac published port by connecting to the IP address of your mac.

Since you mentioned that you want to access your Mac from inside a virtualbox machine, you have a few options:

- (virtualbox host mode networking) - simply connect to the IP address of your mac on the virtualbox host-only network. Usually this will match the IP of the virtualbox VM, but end in `.1`. For example if your virtualbox's ethernet interface that is connected to the host-only network has IP 192.168.30.100, your mac's ip on that host-only network is almost certainly 192.168.30.1. You should be able to see this ip in the output of `ifconfig` on your mac.
- (virtualbox NAT mode networking) - connect to the ip address of the gateway as seen by your virtualbox VM. Virtualbox's host mode networking will forward these connections to your mac's 127.0.0.1
- connect to your mac's en0 ip address. This IP is still reachable from inside your virtualbox VM.

Comment: (virtualbox NAT mode networking) - connect to the ip address of the gateway as seen by your virtualbox VM. Virtualbox's host mode networking will forward these connections to your mac's 127.0.0.1
Worked for me.